# Angular Material mat-checkbox inside mat-list-item(mat-nav-list)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to achieve to have a list of transactions. On hovering an item the checkbox would become visible and selectable, but if the user doesn't want to select the specific item just click on the transaction itself, on the right pane the relevant information would be shown on click(with router params).

My question would be how can I make a material navigation list with the clicks separated by the checkbox, and the mat-list-item itself?

EDIT1:
I was able to make a list with anchor tags, but unfortunately, if I click on the checkbox inside the anchor tag the checkbox doesn't get checked. Can I somehow change this behavior?

```
<mat-nav-list>
<a mat-list-item *ngFor="let transItem of transItems" [routerLink]="transItem.id" routerLinkActive="active" [disableRipple]="true">
    <div mat-list-icon>
        <mat-checkbox [checked]="selection.isSelected(transItem)" (change)="selection.toggle(transItem)"></mat-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div matLine>
         {{ transItem.id }}
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use the mat-tree.
Atleast from your description it sounds like meeting your requirements some how.
https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples

https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src/app/tree-checklist-example.ts

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Seega. Unfortunately, it wouldn't fit in my design because when the user clicks on the mat-list-item the router sets the transaction id as a param and on the right pane there would be a pdf visible, and a few data regarding the transaction.

Now I was able to make a mat-nav-list with anchor tags in it but unfortunately if I click on the checkbox (inside the anchor tag) then nothing happens just the router sets the param. Can I somehow change this behavior?